# Save C# Image to SQLyog Database

Tags: c#, sql, memorystream, sqlyog

I wanna save a picture from pictureBox1 and save it to my database in SQLyog. I have used a lot of codes but none seems to work for me. The data type that I'm using in my database is LONGBLOB.

Example is:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
byte[] PhotoByte = ms.ToArray();

//sql string
_sSQL = "INSERT INTO student_pictures (Picture)" +
        " VALUES (" + Photobyte + ")";

DBConnection sSQL = _sSQL;
```

Comment: `" VALUES ('" + Photobyte + "')";` will convert `Photobyte` to a string using its `.ToString()` method, and since it's an array, it will convert it to the string `"System.byte[]"`.  Your database data type should be some kind of binary representation, not string, and you should use a parameterized SQL query

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I had accidentally added single quotes on the value hence making it save it as string. I still however cannot save the image to my database using this code. Also the data type I am using is LONGBLOB.

Comment: The issue I described will still exist. Parameterized queries are the _only_ solution.